# Centering Issue inline-block div elements

Tags: html, css

I am running into an issue where my `contact-section-left` is not centering in the parent div. This is not a `vertical-align: top` issue. You can see the `border-right` white line, that is showing how much the height extends for the `contact-section-left` div is, but I am it to be the same size as the right side with the image (sorry the example doesn't have the image).

I am not sure if I am going for the wrong approach here or what, but I am wanting it to look like the paint image I made below.

Any ideas?

[image]

```css
.total-center {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
#contact-section {
 width: 100%;
 background: #00a16d;
}
#contact-section-wrap {
 padding: 2%;
}
#contact-section-left, #contact-section-right {
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding: 1% 0;
 position: relative;
}
#contact-section-left {
 width: 60%;
 border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
 font-style: italic;
}
#contact-section-right {
 width: 30%;
 text-align: center;
}
#contact-img {
 background-image: url("../icons/envelope.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 width: 128px;
 height: 128px;
 position: relative;
}
#contact-width {
 width: 200%;
 font-size: 2em;
}
.total-width {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-section">
  <div id="contact-section-wrap">
   <div id="contact-section-left">
    <div class="total-center total-width">Tell us more about your project.</div>
   </div><div id="contact-section-right">
    <div id="contact-img"><span class="total-center" id="contact-width">Contact us</span></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entire code can be simplified as follows. I use a pseudo element for the vertical line in between, and shift the position with `order` via flexbox.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgzzgzzz/)**

```css
#contact-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #00a16d;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

#contact-section:before {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 1px;
  height: 2em;
  background: #fff;
  order: 2;
}

#contact-section-left {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  order: 1;
  font-style: italic;
}

#contact-section-right {
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/cLMHUZE.png") center / contain no-repeat;
  font-size: 2em;
  order: 3;
  padding: .5em 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-section">
  <div id="contact-section-left">Tell us more about your project.</div>
  <div id="contact-section-right">Contact us</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assiging `display: flex; align-items: center;` to the parent of the left/right sections will display them side-by-side and center them vertically. Then if you move the border-right from the left (shorter) element to a border-right of the right (taller) element, the line should look more like you want it.

```css
.total-center {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
#contact-section {
 width: 100%;
 background: #00a16d;
}
#contact-section-wrap {
 padding: 2%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#contact-section-left, #contact-section-right {
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding: 1% 0;
 position: relative;
}
#contact-section-left {
 width: 60%;
 font-style: italic;
}
#contact-section-right {
 width: 30%;
 text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
}
#contact-img {
 background-image: url("../icons/envelope.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 width: 128px;
 height: 128px;
 position: relative;
}
#contact-width {
 width: 200%;
 font-size: 2em;
}
.total-width {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-section">
  <div id="contact-section-wrap">
   <div id="contact-section-left">
    <div class="total-center total-width">Tell us more about your project.</div>
   </div><div id="contact-section-right">
    <div id="contact-img"><span class="total-center" id="contact-width">Contact us</span></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Anyway to get the left section `border-right` white line in between?

Comment: @Paul oh sorry, check my answer again. I copied and pasted and forgot to change `border-right` to `border-left`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `#contact-section-wrap` doesn't have a height. The `height: 100%`s you are setting aren't really doing anything. They still rely on a parent height to have any idea what they're getting 100% of.

Try setting a height on `#contact-section-wrap`.